# Compositing in svg with D3

Tags: html, svg, d3.js

I have been trying to create an SVG by manipulating SVG properties using d3. My objective is to place a smaller rectangle over bigger one and composite the destination using porter duffs "dst-out". Unfortunately the [examples](http://www.svgopen.org/2005/papers/abstractsvgopen/index.html) I tried are not working in my browser. Not sure if it's because of the SVG spec. Here is the code that I have been messing around with

```
    svg.append("g").attr("id","content").append("svg:rect").
        attr("x",0).
        attr("y",200).
        attr("height",100).
        attr("width", width-20).
        attr("fill", "#2d578b");

        d3.select("#chartLaser svg").select("#content").append("svg:rect").
        attr("x",-50).
        attr("y",250).
        attr("height",30).
        attr("width",80).
        attr("fill", "#FF0066").attr("comp-op","src-atop");
```

Any help leading to a solution would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the examples aren't working in your browser, then you won't be able to get it to work with D3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a fragile solution to my question. The best method I have found so far to execute such kind of operations is to use a server (I'm using node js) and convert SVG to Graphics2D using [SVGSalamander](https://svgsalamander.java.net/). After it's converted to Graphics2d, we have a whole array of options - add, subtract, etc. After this again render it to SVG using [Batik](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/). This seems to working for me and currently the best solution I have found. Additionally you can automate this whole process by using [node java](https://github.com/nearinfinity/node-java)

Answer (score 1):

The examples on the site you cite are SVG version 1.2. Currently there is only basic support for SVG 1.1 in most browsers. If you click on any of them images it shows you the SVG version (on the page it falls back to PNG).

As you can tell now your browser probably does not support what you thought it did. There is a good round up of browser compatibility at the end of this [blog post](http://voormedia.com/blog/2012/10/creating-svg-vector-graphics-for-maximum-browser-compatibility) and there is a visual check of the features at this [test page](http://voormedia.com/blog/2012/10/creating-svg-vector-graphics-for-maximum-browser-compatibility/svg-browser-test).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the links, definitely much better than the Wikipedia version showing whats supported :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using an SVG Filter - which is the only way you get to use compositing in SVG 1.1

Comment: SVG filter like feComposite and others can only mask the original svg. I dont think it can change the original SVG by performing porter duff operations.

Comment: What I mean to say is it, using filters will give you the effect of doing such operations like in [this](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/images/FILTERS/Filters_Composite.svg) but the original SVG shape is unchanged. If it is a rectangle, it will still be a rectangle with some filter effects. What I want is to turn it into a path after the other rectangle subtracted from it.

Comment: Yes, you're entirely correct. If you want to have a path object to use afterwards, then this won't do it.